# Should I release or reset the MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

I haave my own Custom Adapter Class called WordAdapter, and I am using a Media Player(named `pronounce`-global variable in the WordAdapter class). I have different activities in which each list item has a linear layout(named as `linearLayout`). I am setting `onClickListener` to it so that when the Linear Layout is clicked, a sound file is played. On completion of playing that sound, I want to free off any unwanted memory. But I do not know if I should use `release()` or `reset()`. I have checked previous questions asked on **SO** before, but I don't think it provides precise explanation for my situation so as to use which method.

**NOTE**: I should be able to play other audio files after this one too (After completing playing this audio file, when I click on other items in the same activity, I should be able to get the sound.)

```
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pronounce = MediaPlayer.create(context, currentWord.getPronounceResourceID());
            pronounce.start();
            pronounce.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
                    //pronounce.release();
                    //pronounce.reset();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You said you have different activities with this functionality. Are you planning to use the same `pronounce` mediaplayer instance for all of them?

Comment: @Shaishav I am not using `pronounce` in any activity other than this `WordAdapter` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a `reset` before a `release`, but I suspect that only `release` is needed.

This might be easier to manage:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (pronounce != null) {
            pronounce.reset();
            pronounce.release();
            pronounce = null;
        }
        pronounce = MediaPlayer.create(context, currentWord.getPronounceResourceID());
        pronounce.start();
   }
```

The `reset` method will simply stop any media and send the MediaPlayer instance back to the idle state. Exactly in the same state when it was created.

The `release` method destroys the media player and frees the majority of the unmanaged resources.  When you call `release`, you should set the instance variable to null so that the remainder of the object is a candidate for garbage collection.

You might have some better performance if you just use reset and then reuse the existing mediaplayer instance on subsequent clicks.

Comment: What if the user clicks in the adapter again and a new file is to be played. In this scenario, won't `release()` be quite overbearing?

Comment: But won't release just render the object useless? For eg, if I click one of the linear layouts, it plays audio and **releases** the object. Then if I click another, won't it be an error?

Comment: If you don't notice any perceived performance degradation (delay) of releasing and creating a new mediaplayer instance on each click, stick with that design since it's the simplest to manage. Otherwise, consider just calling `reset` and using `setDataSource` to change the file being played.

Comment: @selbie If we `release`, we need to call `create()` method again. But if we `reset`, we need to call only `setDataSource()`. **Am I right?** BTW I am not using any AsyncTask until now, as I am learning it still

Comment: After `reset` you can call `setDataSource` followed by `prepare`.  Then you can call `start` again.

Comment: Oh... And for `release`? We have to call `create()` again right? So `release` destroys the instance of the class but not the variable itself?

Comment: If you call `release`, you should immediately set the variable to `null` to call `create` again.  Either way, don't leave the `pronounce` variable referencing a dead object.