# Android Media Player release doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, release

please help, I made a release for MediaPlayer as it was in the tutorial, but it doesn't work, after couple times i play audio it is not working no more. Here is my Code, how can it be fixed?

I have put raw resources in Array so MediaPlayer can play different audio for each item

```
public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mOnComplitionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);


        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        words.add(new Word("one", "lutti", R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.number_one));
        words.add(new Word("two", "otiiko", R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.number_two));
        words.add(new Word("three", "tolookosu", R.drawable.number_three, R.raw.number_three));
        words.add(new Word("four", "oyyisa", R.drawable.number_four, R.raw.number_four));
        words.add(new Word("five", "massokka", R.drawable.number_five, R.raw.number_five));
        words.add(new Word("six", "temmokka", R.drawable.number_six, R.raw.number_six));
        words.add(new Word("seven", "kenekaku", R.drawable.number_seven, R.raw.number_seven));
        words.add(new Word("eight", "kawinta", R.drawable.number_eight, R.raw.number_eight));
        words.add(new Word("nine", "wo'e", R.drawable.number_nine, R.raw.number_nine));
        words.add(new Word("ten", "na'aacha", R.drawable.number_ten, R.raw.number_ten));

        WordAdapter wordAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_numbers);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(wordAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                releaseMediaPlayer();

                Word word = words.get(position);

                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, word.getmAudio());

                
                mMediaPlayer.start();

                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnComplitionListener);

            }

        });

    }
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
            // because we no longer need it.
            mMediaPlayer.release();

            // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
            // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
            // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38811972/3675925

`reset` the mediaPlayer and changing the `dataSource` would be the better option in your code.

simple audio player :

https://github.com/Pankaj-Desai/AudioPlayer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/audioplayer/Player.java

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but i still have a problem. I have added reset before release in releaseMediaPlayer method and it caused no changes, also audio player code that you provided is a little different from mine, I,ve made just a listView with different words, and when you click one of that items, the app is supposed to say it.        and i didnt understand about dataSource at all. Thank you for your help once again